# What does Herb's build-up to broadcast mean?

Tags: the-newsroom

In *The Newsroom*, what is meant when Herb counts down to a broadcast by saying "Roll VTRx right before the intro sequence to News Night begins playing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Roll VTR

means **"Roll Video Tape Recorder"**...

He's giving the instruction to start the playback of the pre-recorded introduction sequence.

It's that simple.

Answer (score 9):

To expand upon Paulie_D’s undeniably correct answer, which I think misses some nuance as to why Herb would say this:

1. Typically, in the old days, a broadcast facility would have an equipment rack (or more) filled with Sony Betacam video tape players (and player-recorders, but IIRC there were some models which lacked a record head). The producer would specify these by name, like “VTR 1.”
2. These highly precise devices required a certain amount of play time to get up to speed (what was occasionally referred to in broadcast technology as the “internal ballistics” - mechanical latency around tensioning the tape correctly and moving the play head to it as well as the time it takes to achieve the correct tape velocity). Because of this, it was necessary to start it a little time ahead of when it was going to be switch to air (a so-called “preroll time” which was typically between three and ten seconds), so if one were planning to play a commercial from a VTR immediately after the initial credits, and one knew the duration of the credits and the preroll time (which a producer would), you could time it so the VTR was playing at the right speed just as the credits ended and the commercial needed to go to air.
3. In general, since the early 2000s, broadcasters have preferred video disk recorders (VDRs) over tape.

Comment: I would expect BetaCAM. BetaMAX was the consumer format; TV stations might use the electrically compatible but higher resolution U-matic.

Comment: Nowadays, a Playout Server with a pre-programmed playlist / cuelist would be used. I have seen studios where there isn't even a producer, director, audio engineer, video operator, camera operator anymore; only the talent. The talent can (literally) step through cues with a footswitch, and the playlist system controls everything from firing clips on the playout server, cueing transitions on the video mixer, advancing the teleprompter, even the robotic cameras. Only when they do a live external interview will there be *one* producer-director who takes over running the cuelist.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica correct, thanks! It has been a long time since I have played with one of these beasts. I have updated my answer.

Comment: for some reason I miss that technology so much.  Never had the problem of downloading a U-matic tape and finding out it's h.265... 'Course, no downloading at all.   @JörgWMittag like the way live shoegaze bands in concert, no longer have 30 effects pedals at their feet, they just have 8 foot buttons, one for each part of the song. Push the button and backstage it switches all the right effects in/out.